# when i was using pointers in function arguments i faced with an error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The error is this:
cannot convert `int*' to`int**' for argument `1' to`bool permition(int**, int, int)' 
Here in code i have a int board[n], and the user gives the 'n'...
i want to give my permition function this array so i had to give it by pointers because the length of it is not specified...So how can i solve this problem
Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
bool permition(int* board[],int place,int n_){
 int m=place;
 while(m!=0){          
             m--;
             if(abs(abs(board[m]-board[place])-abs(m-place))==1 
                && abs(m-place)<3 && abs(board[m]-board[place]))
                 return false;
             }
 return true;     
 }
 void printBoard(int* board[],int n){
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         cout << board[i]<< " ";
 cout << endl;

 }
int main()
{
int p=0;
int n;
cout << "plz: ";
cin >> n;
int board[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        board[i]=0;
while(p<n){
           while((board[p]<n) && permition(board,p,n)==false)
               board[p]+=1;
           if(board[p]<n)
               p++;
           else{
                p--;
                board[p]+=1;
                }
           if(p==n && board[0]<n-1)
    //it means the first number is not max so we should         
    //print and continue from fist again
           {
                   printBoard(board,n);
                   p=0;
                   board[0]+=1;
           }
           }

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `permition` takes an `int **`. You pass an `int *` (after decay).

Comment: Fascinating that it compiles... The board parameter is an array of int* which seems nonsense. However, the "board" parameter is only ever used to calculate the difference between two elements. Since all the elements of board are int*, the code will try to calculate a pointer difference, giving a ptrdiff_t, which can be passed to abs. Didn't know you can write an int* to cout (never tried it, and don't assume it would give any useful output).

Comment: @gnasher729, Sure you can. It gets converted to a `void *` and prints the address stored in the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of [] in the function definition of permition:

```
bool permition(int* board,int place,int n_)
```

See if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
bool permition(int* board[],int place,int n_)
```

to

```
bool permition(int const board[],int place,int n_)
```

The current argument declaration (first above) says that `board` is an array of pointers to `int`, which it isn't.

---

The `[]` ends up as a pointer, so you can alternatively write

```
bool permition(int const* board,int place,int n_)
```

This form has the advantage that you can use `const` also on the pointer, while with `[]` you have a pointer that can be changed but that looks like an array.

The disadvantage is that the declaration no longer communicates "array" to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the original code passes an array of `int` (which is treated as an `int *`) to a function that's declared to take a *pointer* to an array of `int`. Here's a corrected version, with some formatting changes that I hope will be helpful.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Removed unused parameter n_.
bool permission(int board[], int place) {
  int m = place;
  // The original code could return false only if (place - m) < 3,
  // so no need to test when (place - m) >= 3.
  while (m-- > max(0, place - 3) { 
    int board_diff = abs(board[m] - board[place];
    int index_diff = place - m;  // Always >= 0

    if (abs(board_diff - index_diff) == 1 && board_diff != 0) {
      return false;
    }
 }
 return true;     
}

void printBoard(int board[], int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << board[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}

int main() {
  int p = 0;
  int n;
  cout << "plz: ";
  cin >> n;
  int board[n] = { 0 };  // Zeroes entire array.

  while (p < n) {
    // Never compare bool to true or false; just use !bool_var.
    while ((board[p] < n) && !permission(board, p)) {
      board[p]++;
    }
    if (board[p] < n) {
      p++;
    } else {
      board[--p]++;
    }
    if (p == n && board[0] < (n - 1)) {
      // The first number is not max so we should         
      // print and continue from first again
      printBoard(board, n);
      board[p = 0]++;  // Assign and increment.
    }
  }

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int board[];
```

is the same as

```
 int *board;
```

so the solution in my guess is to write that

```
bool permition(int board[],int place,int n_)
void printBoard(int board[],int n)
```

You need to understand and to work more on pointers !